# Qualtrics: Random Sets + Loop on Y/N Response

Tags: loops, random, survey, qualtrics

I have a Qualtrics survey with 73 blocks of languages' cultural information. Each language has three questions and is contained within it's own block.

I am assigning each survey participant a randomized set of 10 languages to respond to. At the end of each set, I would like to ask the participant if they would like to review another set of lanaguegs (10 languages). If they respond NO, they are sent to submit the survey (through Survey End). This part I have easy.

If they respond YES, I want to loop them back through the randomizer so that they get another 10 random languages assigned, so that none from their first set was reseated, and so that it is still equally distributed using the 'evenly presents elements' feature of the randomizer.

I have tried several methods to implement this design but can't figure out a way to loop back to a randomizer if they select YES on the answer.

The closest I got was to add all 73 blocks of languages to a second randomizer, that if YES is selected, they are sent to this new randomizer and a set of 10 languages is given. The problem here, is that there is no guarantee they will not receive a language that was given to them in the first set, and second, this can not be repeated so ultimately they can only review 2 sets of 10 languages (unless I were to add another randomizer, but with each addition, the change of repeating languages increases).

I read about the loop function for a Qualtrics block but since I have each language set up within it's own block, and I want to loop to sets of 10, I don't see how I could implement this solution easily. I set up each language within it's own block because I wanted each language to have it's own page with 3 questions per page, for ease of reading since one of the questions per language is a paragraph with highlighting response.

Any suggestions? I am relatively new to Qualtrics and could be missing something simple, but I have done extensive research to try to find the solution to no avail. Thanks!

I have attached the link to the actual survey, not sure how to link to the dev side of it. https://boisestate.az1.qualtrics.com/SE/?SID=SV_9ZF2ZNjdDRr5mFn

Comment: I may have a suggestion or two. Do you have the ability to write JavaScript or write/host a web service script?

Comment: Not easily. I have practically no experience with JavaScript. I know Ruby but I don't think that would be useful here ;)

Answer (score 0):

An imperfect solution that doesn't require any scripting would be to set an embedded variable for each language to flag when it is done.  Then put each language block inside a branch and execute the block only if the language hasn't been done already.  After the first 10 languages are done, on subsequent passes you would be doing 10 or fewer depending on how many of the random 10 had already been done.

You would be randomizing all 73 on each pass. However, once you set it up for the first one, you just need to duplicate that part of the survey flow for subsequent passes.

Comment: The only downside of this, and you did say it was imperfect, is that it doesn't handle showing elements evenly.

Comment: I'll give this a test try and let you know how it goes. Thanks.